# React: I can't figure how to map my tables using this.state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, csv, uitableview, bootstrap-4

I have 2 `.CSV` files : `"1.csv"` and `"2.csv"` and I want to put each in a table and print it out. My functions **async GetData(file)** and **async FetchCSV(file)** works fine and returns an array of objects exactly what I  need for my `<BootstrapTable />` ***data*** parameter. My **componentDidMount()** loops through those files and changes `this.state.data` for each file.

```
    state = {
        data: [{}],
      };
    
    async FetchCSV(file) {
        const response = await fetch("data/" + file + ".csv");
        const reader = response.body.getReader();
        const result = await reader.read();
        const decoder = new TextDecoder("utf-8");
        const csv = await decoder.decode(result.value);
        return csv;
      }
    
    async GetData(file) {
        const data = Papa.parse(await this.FetchCSV(file));
        const result = [{}];
        for (var i = 1; i < data.data.length - 1; i++) {
          result.push({
            week: data.data[i][0],
            kcal: data.data[i][1],
            exercise: data.data[i][2],
          });
        }
        this.setState({ data: result });
        return console.log("done");
      }
    
      componentDidMount() {
    const patients = ["1", "2"];
    for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
      this.GetData(patients[i]);
    }
  }
```

Here is my render function, I want to print each patient in a table, but my function is printing 7 empty (empty because I tested with the const z to see if it renders) tables but I have 2 patients so it should print 2 tables. The problem is in the render method when I try to print my tables for each `.CSV` file. I tested my table outside the map function (as you can see below) and it works fine. My `{console.log(items)}` prints the items object exactly how I need it, so I don't understand what the problem is

```
render() {
  return (
        <div>
          {
            this.state.data.map(function (items, i) {
              const columns = [
                {dataField: "week",text: "week",},
                {dataField: "kcal",text: "kcal",},
                {dataField: "exercise",text: "exercise",},];
              const z = [{}]; // TO TEST IF IT RENDERS
              return (
                <div>
                  {console.log(items)} // looks fine (it renders outside map function)
                  // data = should be items
                  <BootstrapTable keyField="id" data={z} columns={columns} />
                </div>
              );
            })
          }
          // this one works fine!!!!
          <BootstrapTable
            keyField="id"
            data={this.state.data}
            columns={this.columns}
          />
        </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your columns const

```
const columns = [
                {dataField: "week",text: "week",},
                {dataField: "kcal",text: "kcal",},
                {dataField: "exercise",ext: "exercise",},];
```

should be

```
const columns = [
                {dataField: "week",text: "week",},
                {dataField: "kcal",text: "kcal",},
                {dataField: "exercise",text: "exercise",},];
```

Comment: oh sorry, in program it looks fine ! so that is not the problem